# Is it possible to make a mandatory JSP (in an include)?

Tags: jsp, include

I'm making a jsp(f) that requires a parameter to be set to make any sense.

Therefore I want it to error if it is not provided so that developers don't make a mistake. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would transform the JSP fragment into a JSP tag file, with a required parameter:

`/WEB-INF/tags/hello.tag` :

```
<%@ attribute name="name" required="true" %>
<h2>Hello, ${name}!</h2>
```

That way, your JSP editor will warn you about the missing required parameter, and a JSP using the tag without the required parameter wouldn't compile.

Such a tag would be used like this:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
<myTags:hello name="Stephen"/>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html for more information.

Comment: Yes, this would work. It's for a footer that has a copyright in it and the end year needs to be specified... which means a tag is a bit of overkill. Someone must have done a `<tagExt:mandatory out="${copyrightEndYear}"/>` that does this. Although it may require runtime use of `rtexprvalue` to check the value isn't empty for pass-throughs...

Comment: How is it overkill? You asked for an include with a mandatory parameter, and the above does just that.

Comment: Your answer started off as "transform the JSP fragment into a JSP tag file,"... what you ended up with is not overkill (I'd include the tag in the jspf). I'm just saying that someone (in a "standard" set of taglibs) should have already made a `<%@ attribute name="out" required="true" %>
${out}` tag